# Rails, destroy if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might sound odd, but is there a 'Rails way' to have a model destroyed if a certain attribute is blank? Say I have a model like `tags` with just a name attribute or something, if the user edits the tag and deletes all the text out of the name field in the form I'd like the model to just be deleted.

I'm aware of the `reject_if` method, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the after_save callback, just check the attribute and destroy the model if it's blank. Something like:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save { |tag| tag.destroy if tag.name.blank? }
end
```

Comment: lol, one line not good enough for ya? : ) I know what you mean though. Ruby does tend to spoil you.